# Facebook page: Permission update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I had an unknown permission exception when I tried to update/create/delete or doing anything my Page properties by using FB.api . I tried again by using Graph API Explore but it still gave me same error. I used google for 2 days but there wasn't any correct answer.

Below screenshot is my app Settings in the Adminster Page's account:

http://demos.kksolution.com/Facebook/screenshot/post-update-about-page.jpg

And here is the Graph API Expore screenshots:

demos.kksolution.com/Facebook/screenshot/list-pages.jpg

Next is the error:

demos.kksolution.com/Facebook/screenshot/post-update-about-page.jpg

Please help me. Thanks too much.

Comment: what permissions you asked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a **page** access token.

> **Page Access Token** – These access tokens are similar to user access
>   tokens, except that they provide permission to APIs that read, write
>   or modify the data belonging to a Facebook Page. To obtain a page
>   access token you need to start by obtaining a user access token and
>   asking for the **`manage_pages` permission**. Once you have the user access
>   token you then get the page access token via the Graph API.
>
> *Doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/*

Then use `GET /me/accounts` to get the access token associated to your page.

Comment: Stéphane is right i tried what you asked via page access token & it worked :) voteup

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I'm using wrong token (I thought that we just have 1 token for a session).